# Function for finding in map, overloading operator in map

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, find, overloading

I have class vector2d. I make struct comp. Here is **Vector2d.h** file

```
    class Vector2d{
    int x;
    int y;

public:
    Vector2d(int x, int y): x(x), y(y) {}
    int getX() const{return x;}
    int getY() const{return y;}
    void setX(int x){this->x = x;}
    void setY(int y){this->y = y;}

    bool operator<(const Vector2d &ob) const;
     bool Vector2d::operator==(const Vector2d &ob) const;


};

struct comp
{

    bool operator()(const Vector2d &lhs, const Vector2d &rhs) const
    {
        if (lhs.getX() == rhs.getX())
            return lhs.getY() > rhs.getY();
 
        return lhs.getX() < rhs.getX();
    }
};
```

There is **Vector2d.cpp** file

```
#include "Vector2d.h"

 bool Vector2d::operator<(const Vector2d &ob) const
    {
        return x < ob.x || (x == ob.x && y < ob.y);
    }


 bool Vector2d::operator==(const Vector2d &ob) const
    {
        return x == ob.x && y == ob.y;
    }
```

There is **Piece.h** file

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include "Vector2d.h"
enum Name { KING, QUEEN, BISHOP, KNIGHT, ROOK, PAWN, EMPTY };
enum Color { WHITE, BLACK, NONE };

class Piece{
protected:
    Name name;
    Color color;
    Vector2d position;
    
public:
    Name getName(){return this->name;}
    void setName(Name name){this->name = name;}
    Color getColor(){return this->color;}
    void setColor(Color){this->color = color;}
    Vector2d getPosition(){return this->position;}
    void setPosition(Vector2d position){this->position = position;}
    virtual bool move(Vector2d thatPosition, std::map<Vector2d, Piece> Pieces) = 0; 
};
```

And i try call find() method on map in **Movement.cpp** file

```
#include "Movement.h"

bool ifLegalDiagonal(Vector2d fromPosition, Vector2d toPosition, std::map<Vector2d, Piece, comp>& pieces)
{
    int fromX = fromPosition.getX();
    int fromY = fromPosition.getY();
    int toX = toPosition.getX();
    int toY = toPosition.getY();

    int lenX = toX - fromX;
    int lenY = toY- fromY; 

    if(abs(lenX) == abs(lenY))
    {
        int xDir = lenX / abs(lenX);
        int yDir = lenY / abs(lenY);

        for (int i = 1; i < abs(lenX); i++)
        {   
        
            Name name = pieces.find(new Vector2d(fromX + xDir*i, fromY + yDir*i)).getName(); //there is a problem
            if(name == EMPTY)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

VS code shows me this error

> no instance of overloaded function "std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::find [with _Key=Vector2d, _Tp=Piece, _Compare=comp, _Alloc=std::allocator<std::pair<const Vector2d, Piece>>]" matches the argument list -- argument types are: (Vector2d *) -- object type is:
> std::map<Vector2d, Piece, comp, std::allocator<std::pair<const
> Vector2d, Piece>>>

I don't now what is missing

Answer (score 0):

You're missing two things:

```
class Vector2d{

   // ...

   bool operator<(const Vector2d &ob) const;
```

Since this class already implements an `<` overload, a custom comparator object for `std::map`'s consumption is not required, and doesn't really accomplish much more beyond what that this `<` overload does on its own (unless you need to iterate over the `map` in a very specific order, which is not the case with the shown code). You can likely get rid of it completely. But more to the actual problem you asked about:

```
   pieces.find(new Vector2d ...);
```

This `pieces` map is a map of `Vector2d` objects. It is not a map of pointers to `Vector2D` objects. Since it's a map of `Vector2d` objects, the parameter that gets passed to `find()` must also be a `Vector2d` object, too. After all, if this was a map of `int`s, you'll need to pass an `int`, instead of an `int *` to `find()`. Just because the map's key is an object instead of a plain `int` doesn't change how `find()` works.

However, `new` creates a new object in dynamic scope and gives you a pointer to it, and that's what you're passing to `find()`. Even if this worked, this is a memory leak.

Simply get rid of the `new`.

Comment: I delete new and it works. Thanks for solving my problem.